How I can bypass Cloudfare using Selenium?
I'm doing automation for my company and there's a step where I need to log in, but this login part requires Cloudfare verification. I turned to chatgpt to try to help me but I didn't get much result. I started doing this type of code recently, so I don't have much knowledge about the area.
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from time import sleep

usuario = 'XXXXX'
senha = 'XXXXX'

Tk().withdraw() 
arquivo_csv = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Arquivos CSV', '*.csv')])

chrome_driver_path = "C:/WebDriver/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe"

service = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")  # Remove a flag de automação

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

stealth(driver,
    languages=["en-US", "en"],
    vendor="Google Inc.",
    platform="Win32",
    webgl_vendor="Google Inc.",
    renderer="ANGLE (Google Inc.)",
    fix_hairline=True,
)

driver.get('https://oikos.corbee.com.br/')
sleep(5)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))

campo_login = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "usuario")))
campo_login.send_keys(usuario)

campo_senha = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']")))
campo_senha.send_keys(senha)

sleep(60)

driver.quit()


why do you wish to bypass a DDoS protection tool? what kind of company and automation is that?

@maxis112 the idea wouldn't be to "ignore" it completely, it would just be to ensure verification using selenium. Because using the code it identifies it as a robot and does not allow me to complete the automation. The automation would be to update some tables that we have automatically, as it takes a lot of our team's time to do so.

Well, that is exactly what it is designed to do: prevent automated access, like the one you are trying.

indeed true, i agree.-- upvoted Klaus D.

Until your company provides a workaround for the QA Team, you can bypass the Cloudflare CAPTCHA using SeleniumBase UC Mode. The following example is custom made for your site:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    url = "https://oikos.corbee.com.br/login.php"
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 6)
    sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
    sb.type('[name="usuario"]', "username")
    sb.type("#password", "password")
    # sb.click("#logar")
    sb.sleep(4)

Here's another one that uses the Driver() format:
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
try:
    url = "https://oikos.corbee.com.br/login.php"
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 6)
    driver.uc_gui_click_captcha()
    driver.type('[name="usuario"]', "username")
    driver.type("#password", "password")
    # driver.click("#logar")
    driver.sleep(4)
finally:
    driver.quit()

If running on Linux is a must, use the SB() format. You can access raw selenium methods from there using sb.driver.
